# Best way to print across multiple pieces of paper?

Tags: fonts, printing, paper, typography

My printer can only print on 8.5x11 sheets of paper and i'm looking to "blow up"/magnify a single word big enough that i can print it across maybe 6 pieces of paper and some how stitch them together.

Is there a program or method that would work best for this?

I'm using a mac.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write your word in a program such as GIMP so that you can save it as an image file in the desired dimensions. You will then be able to open it in [PosteRazor](http://posterazor.sourceforge.net/) and export a multi-page .pdf file.

> The PosteRazor cuts a raster image into pieces which can afterwards be printed out and assembled to a poster.

Comment: PosteRazor will do the trick and works with any image.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is a basic function for almost all designing programs.

I have tested by Adobe Illustrator creative suite 5. The steps:

1. Input the word and make it to vector by "create outline".
2. Enlarge to the size what you want.
3. Print with "tile" option.

Answer (score 0):

Try Excel. It is very good at splitting content across pages.

Comment: Could you expand on the answer with some instructions for the OP or other users seeing this from Google?